# Partial differential equations burgers equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve non-linear partial differential equation using 
the **hyperbolic functions method** or the **first integral method**,
but I can’t find resources online.
Can anyone help me find some resources?

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: Are the words "characteristic curve", "Lagrange equations" resp. "Lagrange-Charpit equations", "complete integral" somehow related to your method?

Comment: The title is confusing ! I was wondering about the *cheese burger* and the *hamburger*  equations ! Back to serious **Burgers' equation** or **Bateman–Burgers equation**. Cheers :-)